# Print indices of columns that are selected on click using the DT package in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

I have a selectable DT and a radio button that changes the orientation of the selection. I am able to print the index of the selections when the radio button is set to rows, but I don't know how to show the indices when the radio button is set to columns. Is there a way of printing the column indices instead of printing a `NULL` when the radio buttons are set to columns?

Here is my MRE:

```
library(shiny)
library(glue)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tibble)

####Create the matrix and organization for the 96 well plate####
plate96 <- function(id) {
  div(
    style = "position: relative; height: 500px",
    tags$style(HTML('
          
        .wells {
            transform: translateX(50%);
        }

        .wells tbody tr td:not(:first-of-type) {
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 15px;
            width: 15px;
            padding: 15px;
            font-size: 0;
        }

    ')),
    div(
      style = "position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-100%);",
      div(
        class = "wells",
        DTOutput(id, width = "90%", height= "100%")
      )
    )
  )
}


renderPlate96 = function(id, colors = rep("white", 96)) {
  stopifnot(is.character(colors) && length(colors) == 96)
  
  plate <- matrix(1:96, 
                  nrow = 8, 
                  ncol = 12, 
                  byrow = TRUE, 
                  dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:8], 1:12))
  
  colnames (plate) = stringr::str_pad(colnames(plate), 2, "left", "0")
  
  return(plate_return1 <-
           datatable(
             plate,
             options = list(dom = 't', ordering = F),
             selection = {if (id == "Horizontal") {list(target = "row")} 
               else if (id == "Vertical") {list(target = "column")}},
             class = 'cell-border compact'
           ) %>%
           formatStyle(
             1:12,
             cursor = 'pointer',
             backgroundColor = styleEqual(1:96, colors, default = NULL)
           )
  )
  
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  
  plate96("plate"),
  tags$b("Wells Selected:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("plateWells_selected"),
  
  
  ####Horizontal vs Vertical orientation radio buttons####
  radioButtons("orientation_radio",
               label = h3("Horizontal vs Vertical"),
               c("Horizontal, counted down rows" = "Horizontal",
                 "Vertical, counted down columns" = "Vertical")),
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  ####Create the 96 well plate image####
  output$plate <- renderDT({
    renderPlate96({as.character(input$orientation_radio)})
  })
  
  output$plateWells_selected <- renderPrint({
    input$plate_rows_selected
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more Googling, I found the answer.

The answer is given here:

https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html

2.1.2 Column Selection
Row selection is the default mode in DT. You can turn on column selection using `datatable(..., selection = list(target = 'column'))`. In this case, you can click on any cell to select a column, and the (numeric) indices of the selected columns will be available in `input$tableId_columns_selected`.

You may also select rows and columns simultaneously using `target = 'row+column'`. In this case, column selection is achieved by clicking on the table footer. Clicking on the table body will select/deselect rows.